# Should we reassign the spartan tag?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, retag-request

I noticed that some users use the spartan tag for a Microsoft product (new browser engine ? - I'm not up to date on this).

Currently, the tag is assigned to a low cost FPGA device family from Xilinx. This chip is old, but still used and popular on development boards.

- We could introduce a new and clear tag for that Microsoft thing or
- rename the current tag in all questions to something like `spartan-fpga` or `xilinx-spartan`.

If renaming is wished, one must consider that there are other tags like virtex, cyclone, stratix, zynq ..., which are all together FPGA device families from Xilinx or Altera. So all tags should have the same structure like `<vendor>-<dev family>`.

Comment: First, what questions are they actually *asking*?  Second, I'm reluctant to use codenames as tags. They quickly fall out of use/favor once the project's formally been launched.

Comment: I just did a few searches through the tag, and I haven't spotted anything on the spartan tag about a Microsoft product. I would suggest following Makoto's first point to make this a little more clear what's wrong.

Comment: Have you tried submitting edits for the tags?

Comment: Many users - in the last month or so - asked for advice in the topics of internet explorer, iis and so on. They used the spartan tag on their questions. I suggested edits on that questions that removed the spartan tag, because it a chip. I thought if it's a new product one should consider to retag all old questions. As Hans stated it's s code name, so I'll go on and exchange spartan tags if the are not related to FPGAs.

Comment: @JaredBurrows Editing that tag won't help because that will break all correct tagged FPAG questions on Spartan devices.

Comment: Reassign the Spartans? Never! In all honesty though, this shouldn't be done. I don't see any posts in the sparta tag which reference internet explorer.

Comment: Sorry the SE app does not allow to copy question links. Here is one example: "can't open localhost in project spartan on windows-10 preview". I already removed the spartan tag from many not FPGA related questions. My meta question was: Is this a new product / should we retag to reduce false tagging. **=> NO**

Comment: @Paebbels Then he would know that is not accepted from the community. So he might well try to create new tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spartan was the dev project name, it now has an official product name: [Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/windows/browser-for-doing).  Well, that's taken, retag them to [microsoft-edge].

Comment: Sure not [ms-edge], like [ms-word] and the like? On further investigation, it seems evenly split between [microsoft-\*] and [ms-\*]...

Comment: Retag which questions specifically? There are 53 in the spartan tag, and none of them reference internet explorer nor microsoft technology. The closest match would be one question from 2009 asking about spartan in c#. I don't think any of these should be retagged.

Comment: The questions that somebody already retagged.

Comment: @HansPassant - It wasn't clear they had been retagged already. Perhaps you can indicate that in your answer so that people wont review the current set if it has already been retagged?