# Collating edges

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

There are tags [edge-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edge-browser) and [microsoft-edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-edge) which IMHO describe the same new Microsoft browser. As of now, [microsoft-edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-edge) appears to be ahead, leading with 105:4 tagged questions plus owning a longer wiki entry and [legacy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294761). I'd propose to remove [edge-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edge-browser), or to make it a synonym for [microsoft-edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-edge).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[edge-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edge-browser) -> [microsoft-edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-edge) - merged and syn'd.